# Impala - exists (subquery) VS 0 < (select count(*)...)

Tags: sql, aggregate, exists, impala

These queries run in Impala.

Two similar queries that should have the same result, but have two different results.

This query gets all the results expected (about 130 in my real case)

```
select field1, field2, concrete_date
from tableA a
where exists(select *
    from tableB b
    where b.field1 = a.field1
        and b.concrete_date > (a.concrete_date + interval -5 minutes) 
        and b.concrete_date < (a.concrete_date + interval  5 minutes) 
)
```

This query returns a little portion of results (about 10 in my real case)

```
select field1, field2, concrete_date
from tableA a
where 0 < (select count(*)
    from tableB b
    where b.field1 = a.field1
        and b.concrete_date > (a.concrete_date + interval -5 minutes) 
        and b.concrete_date < (a.concrete_date + interval  5 minutes) 
)
```

Where is the difference between?? I can't see it...

In my tests, if I take one concrete value of field1 from my first query (but that doesn't appear in the second query results) and force the subquery changing the 'a.concrete_date' with the date that corresponds to that field1, the second query returns the expected row ok

```
select field1, field2, concrete_date
from tableA a
where 0 < (select count(*)
    from tableB b
    where b.field1 = 'XXXXX'
        and b.concrete_date > ('2017-01-01 00:00:00' + interval -5 minutes) 
        and b.concrete_date < ('2017-01-01 00:00:00' + interval  5 minutes) 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

where b.field1 = a.field2
where b.field1 = a.field1

There's the difference.

Comment: It is an error in the query sample, not in the real query.